# AFNetworking 2.0 - AFSecurityPolicy subclass not working

Tags: afnetworking-2

I am trying to perform some SSL certificate checking that isn't done in the default AFSecurityPolicy (even with various flags set).

I have subclassed AFSecurityPolicy and am returning NO from evaluateServerTrust:forDomain: for testing purposes. I have verified that my class is being called.

AFNetworking's NSURLConnectionDelegate is in the class AFURLConnectionOperation. In the delegate callback, after I return NO, it is calling
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

The HTTP request completes and I am getting the expected data from the server.

I would expect the HTTP request to not be made after the authentication challenge is cancelled.

Comment: Maybe post the code? Seems like you're doing everything right.